ngrok server cannot find routes
I use ngrok to test my API. It is located in the folder with my API project, when I launch it and try to make a request, I get error 404 on all ports except 8000, I get error 502 on it.
Approximate address: https://c827-46-34-192-75.ngrok-free.app/api/news
I am writing an API on the Laravel framework, all routes are in the routes folder in the file api.php.
I tried changing the ports, but it didn't help.

can you share some more information, how do you configure your routes?
